# How to hide these modules with internal user in Odoo 13?

Tags: module, settings, odoo, internals, access-rights

I would like to hide Apps and Settings modules with internal user in Odoo 13. Just the administrator could control these modules!

How to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hide apps and setting by removing permission in application access. In user setting screen you can find administration field there, select the blank option.

Comment: Hi Thayif, I am now can hide these modules via your instruction. But I received the information after login to Odoo by internal user. It show: "Sorry, you are not allowed to access documents of type 'Model Access' (ir.model.access). This operation is allowed for the groups: - Administration/Access Rights - (Operation: read, User: 9) ." How to turn off this information?

Comment: @Khanh does this information show immediately after login or at time you are trying to access any other menu or model

Comment: Yes, this information show immediately after login.

Answer (score 0):

Both menues are already hidden for "normal" users, because both menues are restricted to the access group "Administration / Settings". Only the admin user account is a member of this access group in default Odoo installations/setups.

Comment: Hi CZoellner, I already changed to Administration / Settings for internal user via administrator. But these modules still show like that.